# How to get a list with all the hosts connected to a domain? (CentOS 6.5)

Tags: linux, ldap

I want to print a list of all the hosts connected to the domain.

I'm looking for a command which does more or less what that one in Powershell does, but for Linux:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}
```

So, what I want to do is getting a list with all the hosts on a domain and then compare it with all the hosts which are already monitored with Nagios.

The computer on which the command will be executed is the Nagios-server (not on the DC itself).

Comment: I’m not sure whether this should be on Super User or on Server Fault, but it’s off topic here. Can you please clarify about which kind of “domain” are you talking? LDAP?

Comment: Yes, LDAP. Ooh, sorry if I'm on the wrong forum!
So, what I want to do is getting a list with all the hosts on a domain and then compare it with all the hosts which are already monitored with Nagios.

Comment: Could you edit your question so that it is clear you’re talking about ldap and clarify where the ldap server is (from the point of view of your linux shell: is it on the same host or are you connecting via network)? Also try to add the [tag:ldap] tag if it is available here, the [tag:list] tag is not applicable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no convenient wrappers that intergrates with Active Directory as the cmdlets you have in powershell. However, Active Directory is an LDAP server, and you can pull out the info with the `ldapsearch` tool, this query fetches all the registred computers in out Active Directory domain:

```
ldapsearch -LLL  -H ldap://ad.ourdomain.local  -x  -D 'OURDOMAIN\user' -w 'thepassword' -b 'dc=ourdomain,dc=local' 'objectClass=computer' name
```

- `ad.ourdomain.local` is the host name or IP address of an active directory domain controller.
- `OURDOMAIN\user` is your domain name, and an existing user name (e.g. ACME\Jon). i.e. the username one uses when logging into a domain account on a windows machine
- `thepassword` is the password of the above user Jon
- `dc=OURDOMAIN,dc=local` is the top level LDAP DN, e.g. `dc=acme,dc=local`, it might be dc=acme,dc=com`, or something else. I don't know an easy way to figure it out except pulling the info out of [ADExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx)

Comment: Using ldapsearch something like ldapsearch -H ldap://ad.ourdomain.local:389 -x -D 'OURDOMAIN\user' -W -b "" -s base "(objectClass=*)" "defaultnamingContext" "objectClass"    Will tell the "top level LDAP DN".  using nslookup -type=any _ldap._tcp.<ourdomain>.net    Will provide a list of most Domain Controllers. (Assuming DNS is in the same namespace as the client.)